# hector_localization

Tags: ros, imu, hector-localization, position

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,
if anyone could help i'd be grateful.
I chose that topic, but if anyone knows about any other package/stack that could solve my problem, shoot!. :D

I am looking for a package that estimates a robot's position over time, using only the information of an IMU.(if there is one...)

I probably found one(hector_localization) that can solve my problem, however
I cant make it work. It compiled without any problem, I changed the subscribed topic to have the same name as the one published by my lse_xsens. I can get the orientations but not the position. I dont know if it needs the information of gps or any other sensor to work.
I found no information explaining how to use, so I'd appreciate any help I can get.
Thanks.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/30376/hector_localization/) by [PedroS.](https://answers.ros.org/users/2042/pedros./) on ROS Answers with karma: 73 on 2012-03-23

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [dornhege](https://answers.ros.org/users/122/dornhege/) on 2012-03-24**:
Does only IMU mean: no laser or similar?

**Comment by [PedroS.](https://answers.ros.org/users/2042/pedros./) on 2012-03-24**:
yes I only have the information that comes from the imu. I know it's not the best way to do things but that's what i got.

**Comment by [Astronaut](https://answers.ros.org/users/2221/astronaut/) on 2013-01-24**:
Hi. I would like to use hector_localization too, but I can make it run. It compiles but I dont know how to run and what parameters it need. Any help?

**Comment by [dornhege](https://answers.ros.org/users/122/dornhege/) on 2013-01-25**:
If you have a new question open one instead of commenting on other question. You will also need to describe your actual problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

In the case of IMU only hector_localization and in fact all localization algorithms aren't applicable. The only thing you can do is integrate information from the IMU depending on what kind of information you get.

For the xsens that means integrating the xyz accelerations and gyros. Expect high drift, very quickly, though.

---

Originally posted by [dornhege](https://answers.ros.org/users/122/dornhege/) with karma: 31395 on 2012-03-24

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi, I am the author of hector_localization. As Christian already mentioned, hector_localization cannot give you velocity or position information from pure IMU measurements only. In fact, it only estimates the pose and twist components that are observable from the measurements you have and fixes the rest. You can check (and publish if you want) the current status information using the PoseEstimation::getSystemStatus() method.

Documentation for hector_localization is still missing and we plan to add some more features within the next weeks before announcing the stack and consider it as more or less stable. However, we already are using it successfully to estimate the pose of our [Hector rescue robot](http://www.gkmm.tu-darmstadt.de/rescue) and the [Hector quadrotor](http://www.ros.org/wiki/hector_quadrotor) by fusing IMU, compass, barometer, GPS and pose updates from the [hector_slam](http://www.ros.org/wiki/hector_slam) stack.

---

Originally posted by [Johannes Meyer](https://answers.ros.org/users/1634/johannes-meyer/) with karma: 1266 on 2012-04-02

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Astronaut](https://answers.ros.org/users/2221/astronaut/) on 2013-01-02**:
Hello. I have a problem using hector mapping. I would like to fuse the IMU data in the slam system. So any help how to use hector_localization and hector slam???

**Comment by [ETS-Dronolab](https://answers.ros.org/users/4112/ets-dronolab/) on 2013-03-22**:
Hi, I have the same issue here! Is it still planned to have more documentation on this stack (hector_localization) ? We would like to use it to fuse IMU and hector slam data to get a robust navigation data.

**Comment by [Astronaut](https://answers.ros.org/users/2221/astronaut/) on 2013-03-22**:
I still did not fix the problem. IS there any improvement or more help on hector_lokalization??